# Orchard Projections & Collapse Accordion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, accordion, orchardcms

I've created a custom content type and a Projection page of them, but cannot shoehorn all the various Parts and Fields into a Bootstrap [Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse).

I am encountering two problems: I have too many characters in the Layout's Property Rewrite Results; or if I add, for example, `@Display(Model.ContentItem.FunOpp.FunTitle.Value)` to the custom .cshtml shape, I get a `'Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem' does not contain a definition for 'FunOpp'` error; or something similar depending upon my layout.

The custom content type definition is:

**Fields:**

- Sponsor (Text Field)
- ​Funding Opportunity (Link Field)
- ​Funding Title (Text Field)
- Closing/Due Date (Text Field)
- Funding Opportunity
- Number (Text Field)
- Accordion Collapse Number (Text Field)

**Parts:**

- Body

I need the Funding Title to be the Accordion-Heading; and all the remaining Fields & Parts to be the Accordion-Inner.

There is a lot of content, and Bootstrap's Collapse requires a lot of markup, so obviously I am getting the "too many characters" error if I go the Token/Rewrite Results route for the Accordion-Inner.

Yet I don't know enough MVC/Razor to determine why I'm getting the Model.ContentItem errors.

Any help would be appreciated, be it somehow combining the Tokens in the Rewrite Output to save characters; or a way to display the various @Model.ContentItem.FunOpp.xxx.Value

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand much of the plumbing but Content Item is a class, but also a dynamic object. You are currently trying to get FunOpp from the class, which doesn't have such a property, only the dynamic object content item does. So you will need to do...

```
@{
  dynamic item = Model.ContentItem;
  var funtitle = item.FunOpp.FunTitle.Value;
}
```

Something along those lines

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this and similar code but to no avail; but I'm sure I'm missing something--seems if you want to do anything beyond 'out of the box' it takes a lot of programming acumen. Which I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Module "Shape Tracer" to see the exact structure of the Model. This is the best way to figure out what orchard is doing under the hood.

Comment: I have, which is how I got the `Model.ContentItem.FunOpp.FunTitle.Value` shape. The issue is I then don't know how best utilize the code Hazza provided without getting the same "does not contain a definition" error. Thanks though!